# Using Wikidata label service in federated queries

Tags: sparql, wikidata, federated-queries

I'm wondering if it is possible to use Wikidata label service in a federated query. E.g., the following query

```
# Query from a local SPARQL enpoint

select ?item ?itemLabel
where {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
        ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.
        SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
    }

}
```

returns empty `?itemLabel`s. How can I get also `?itemLabel`s in my resultset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use the [manual mode](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/SERVICE_-_Label#Manual_Label_SERVICE), it's just one line more in your case:

```sql
PREFIX       wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX        wd:  <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX        bd:  <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX  wikibase:  <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX      rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * {
  SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql> {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "it". ?item rdfs:label ?label }
  }
}
```

[Try on FactForge](http://factforge.net/sparql?name=&infer=false&sameAs=false&query=PREFIX+++++++wdt%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0APREFIX++++++++wd%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX++++++++bd%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0APREFIX++wikibase%3A++%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX++++++rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT+*+%7B%0A++SERVICE+%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E+%7B%0A++++%3Fitem+wdt%3AP31+wd%3AQ146.%0A++++SERVICE+wikibase%3Alabel+%7Bbd%3AserviceParam+wikibase%3Alanguage+%22it%22.+%3Fitem+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Flabel%7D%0A++%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 3):

Include some of the things that are nominally optional...  Here's the full [query](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20wikibase%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ146%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22[AUTO_LANGUAGE]%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) I just ran through [URIBurner.com](http://URIBurner.com), and its [results](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20wikibase%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20*%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fquery.wikidata.org%2Fsparql%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ146%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22[AUTO_LANGUAGE]%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000).

```
PREFIX       wdt:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
PREFIX        wd:  <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX        bd:  <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>
PREFIX  wikibase:  <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>

SELECT *
WHERE
  {
    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>
      {
        SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
        WHERE 
          {
            ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146 .
            SERVICE wikibase:label
              { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
          }
      }
  }
```